# How to fix "unknown directive rewrite_by_lua_block" error in nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, lua

When I try running nginx in ubuntu with: "service nginx start" it starts giving me this error. any idea how to solve this problem?

I've tried to download lua modules because I thought maybe that was the cause, but it did not work. I don't know if I downloaded it wrong or if that just wasn't the problem.

```
//nginx.conf file:

worker_processes  auto;

events { 
worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;
        }
        location ~* \.css$ {
            rewrite_by_lua_block {
               local new_uri = ngx.re.sub(ngx.var.uri , ".*/([a-z0-9.-]+.css$)", "/$1" , "mijo")
            ngx.req.set_uri(new_uri)
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR , ngx.var.uri ,  " " , new_uri)
        }
        root html;
        }
    }

}
```

Any idea how I could start the program?

Comment: Nginx will need to be rebuilt to include LUA functionality. `nginx -V` should confirm that the LUA module has been included.

Comment: Lua is not included is there a tutorial or somthing somewhere on the internet because I tried to install it many times in many different websites

Comment: I was looking at [this page](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/)

Comment: I know that page I tried it several times with the manual installation.I came all the way to the last stap en then I try to "make" the tar file it says it cant find the path and cant make it for that reason

Comment: https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#installation the last step with the make commands thats where I am stuck at please help!

Comment: If it's a build problem, you should probably ask your question and provide specific details on Superuser or Unix & Linux.